# Relation between two tables (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables : 
users that contain the following columns:

```
userID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
name varchar(50)
address varchar(30)
phone varchar(11)
email varchar(255)
username int(9) 
password int(9)
account_permissions enum('a','b','c')
status enum('0','1')
```

and 
private message table that contain the following columns :

```
 id auto_increment primary key
to_user varchar(50)
from_user varchar(50)
subject varchar(400)
message text
date date 
del  tinyint(1) default value 0
```

How can I connect the two tables , if user's name will change in the future so I want that it will change automatically in the to_user/from_user columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the private message table to make the to_user an from_user columns be INT(11). They should be foreign keys to the users table userID column.

That way if you ever change the users name in the users table, the joins will remain intact and be unaffected, because it's joined by the unique user identifier.

Also I thikn the username and password fields should be varchar rather than int?

So you might have:

```
users
userID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
name varchar(50) 
address varchar(30) 
phone varchar(11) 
email varchar(255) 
username varchar(9)
password varchar(9) 
account_permissions enum('a','b','c') status enum('0','1')

messages
id auto_increment primary key 
to_user int(11)
from_user int(11)
subject varchar(400) 
message text 
date date 
del tinyint(1) default value 0
```

then you could look at the messages like this:

```
SELECT
    fromuser.username AS from_user,
    touser.username AS to_user,
    messages.subject,
    messages.message,
    messages.date
FROM
    messages
INNER JOIN
    users AS fromuser ON messages.from_user = fromusers.userID
INNER JOIN
    users AS touser ON messages.to_user = tousers.userID
```

or if you want to add a new message, you just insert the user id's rather than the names.

Comment: Ok, but now my code  is insert name from users to to_user/from_user data . how i need to change the code that it will take the name according to foregin key

Comment: @surfer that particular question has been answered here many times.

Comment: the problem is that when user wants to send message he does not know user id he will see names , the names will come through the query from users table.   I have a big mess. what you recommend to do : create new db and edit the queries in site features? or something else?

Comment: I have funny situation : I did the following query :          $sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM private_message,users WHERE private_message.from_user = users.userID  and it show me only messages that sent to me and not by me (me= user in the system) but how it possible without any  verification. someone can explain?